# how use session without secret in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I print the Session Its convert by secret.But i want pure value like if id = "52" but got "7OvNNopdEjLcal32ObN95MnVnRuzrZpI"

**app.js file**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**route.js file**

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

        var sess = req.session;
   ...
   ...
  sess.id = results[0].client_id;
            //res.end('done');
            console.log(sess.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secret` option when initializing your session store is required when using `express-session`. If you don't set a secret, then an error will be thrown. And yes, the secret is used to generate the long hash that is used as the session.id, which **can not be modified**. This makes your session more secure and more likely to have a unique id.

However, you can still add the `client_id` to your session! Instead of setting it as the `id` you can add it as an additional property on your req.session object:

```
var sess = req.session;
sess.client_id = results[0].client_id;
```